# Why do we want to use a helper method in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I came across this block of code when I was studying for java CS61b, which used a helper method. As to why we use helper method, the explanation I got is that it makes it easier to do the recursive task. But I have trouble visualizing the alternative options where we don't use a helper method because I have difficulting write the solution. Does that mean using a helper method is the only way? I wish I could compare the two solutions and better understand the usage of a helper method.

here's the code in question:

```
    //Same as get, but uses recursion.
    public int getRecursive(int index) {
        if (index>size-1) {
            return 0;
        }
        node p = sentinel;
        return getRecursiveHelper(p, index);
    }

    public int getRecursiveHelper(node p, int i) {
        if (i==0) {
            return p.next.item;
        } else {
            p = p.next;
            i -= 1;
        }
        return getRecursiveHelper(p, i);

    }
```

the below is the full code:

```
public class LinkedListDeque {



    public node sentinel;
    public int size;

    public class node {
        public node prev;
        public int item;
        public node next;

        public node(node p, int i, node n) {
            prev = p;
            item = i;
            next = n;
        }
    }

    // Creates an empty list
    public LinkedListDeque() {
        sentinel = new node(null, 63, null);
        sentinel.prev = sentinel;
        sentinel.next = sentinel;
        size = 0;
    }



    // Adds an item of type T to the front of the deque.
    public void addFirst(int x) {
        sentinel.next = new node(sentinel, x, sentinel.next);
        sentinel.next.next.prev = sentinel.next;
        size += 1;
    }



    // Adds an item of type T to the back of the deque.
    public void addLast(int x) {
        sentinel.prev = new node(sentinel.prev, x, sentinel);
        sentinel.prev.prev.next = sentinel.prev;
        size += 1;
    }


    // Returns true if deque is empty, false otherwise.
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    // Returns the number of items in the deque.
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }


    // Prints the items in the deque from first to last, separated by a space. Once all the items have been printed, print out a new line.
    public void printDeque() {
        node p = sentinel.next;
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            System.out.print(p.item + " ");
            p = p.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    // Removes and returns the item at the front of the deque. If no such item exists, returns null.
    public int removeFirst() {
        if (size==0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int x = sentinel.next.item;
        sentinel.next = sentinel.next.next;
        sentinel.next.prev = sentinel;
        size -= 1;
        return x;
    }


    // Removes and returns the item at the back of the deque. If no such item exists, returns null.
    public int removeLast() {
        if (size==0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int x = sentinel.prev.item;
        sentinel.prev = sentinel.prev.prev;
        sentinel.prev.next = sentinel;
        size -= 1;
        return x;

    }

    // Gets the item at the given index, where 0 is the front, 1 is the next item, and so forth. If no such item e
    public int get(int index) {
        if (index>size-1) {
            return 0;
        }
        node p = sentinel.next;
        for (int i=0; i<index; i++) {
            p = p.next;

        }
        return p.item;
    }


    //Same as get, but uses recursion.
    public int getRecursive(int index) {
        if (index>size-1) {
            return 0;
        }
        node p = sentinel;
        return getRecursiveHelper(p, index);
    }

    public int getRecursiveHelper(node p, int i) {
        if (i==0) {
            return p.next.item;
        } else {
            p = p.next;
            i -= 1;
        }
        return getRecursiveHelper(p, i);

    }









    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListDeque L = new LinkedListDeque();
        L.addFirst(2);
        L.addFirst(1);
        L.addFirst(0);
        L.addLast(3);
        L.addLast(4);
        L.addLast(5);
        System.out.println(L.get(7));




    }

}
```

Comment: A `public` helper is kind of silly. A `private` helper hides implementation details (like the fact that it is recursive), prevents open recursion (which is often undesired), and allows lots of JIT optimizations like tail-call elimination.

Comment: (Sorry about first comment, I saw the context later.) `Does that mean using a helper method is the only way?` I think so.  The recursive method needs an extra parameter that `getRecursiveHelper` uses, so the `getRecursive` method just starts the process, and the helper method (with the extra parameter) does the actual recursive work.

Comment: So you could do without the helper, but solutions without the helper method would be undersireable for various reasons (expose internal fields, etc.) so the helper technique is just a convenient way to keep the publicly used methods clean.  (And as Silivio mentions the helper method could be and probably should be private, which would also help clean up the publicly accessible methods.)

Comment: You _could_ do it nonrecursively with a loop, I suppose.

Comment: As a side note, this is a badly written recursive method as it unnecessarily modifies the parameter variables. A clean version would be `int getRecursiveHelper(node p, int i) { if(i==0) { return p.next.item; } else { return getRecursiveHelper(p.next, i - 1); } }`